# Using Python in Presto Query

Tags: python, presto

Is there any way to insert Python code into SQL?
It is possible to do so for Microsoft SQL Server as shown in this example: https://www.tableau.com/about/blog/2017/12/how-use-tableau-sql-server-r-and-python-78882

However I need to do it for Presto (for exactly the same reason - piping data into Tableau).

Appreciate any advice please. Thank you.

Comment: You could write python code externally to query and write results back to the backing catalog

Answer (score 1):

Not deeply familiar with SQLServer scripting abilities but in example you provided many variables and stored procedures were used.

1. Presto does not support calling stored procedures or functions from connectors.
2. Presto can not set a variables for further executions.

I hope this helps you